# ProFTPD - File owner is www-data instead of connected user

Tags: ftp, sftp

For some reason, when I ftp in using ProFTP, files I create are owned by `www-data:www-data`. I'd like them to be owned by `myusername:www-data`. The strange thing is, there's nothing in the files in `/etc/proftpd` that mentions `www-data`.

User's info:

```
$ id user1
uid=1002(user1) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
$ grep 1002 /etc/passwd
user1:x:1002:33:User,,,:/home/user1:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Please can you check if the UID of both users is the same?

Comment: I don't see how two users on a Linux system would have the same UID. I checked anyway, and no.. all UIDs are unique.

Comment: Are your ProFTPD configuration employing "Virtual Users" as for http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/VirtualUsers.html and, if yes, which is the UID assigned to the username you're using? P.S.: as for your previous doubts: main passwd file is subject to (error-prone) manual handling :-)

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli No, using real users that are in /etc/passwd.

Comment: What they're asking you to do is check /etc/passwd for the UIDs. If they had manually assigned UIDs somehow, they'd have that. **grep myusername /etc/passwd** and **grep www-data /etc/passwd**. Please display the results here if you can.

Comment: @MichaelBailey Edited my post.

Comment: What is ProFTPD being run by? Kinda a moonshot but...

Comment: Ugh, I was connecting to the wrong port! I guess I have to let this question get dusty, because I can't delete it now that it has a bounty on it.

Comment: That seems like one hell of a SF flaw. Can you self-award it?

Comment: Just answer it yourself and mark your own answer correct?

Comment: AFAIK you [can't award the bounty to yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120242/what-happens-to-a-bounty-if-you-accept-your-own-answer)   so the fake Internet points are gone.

Comment: Man that's depressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making sure you're using the right port number next time! ;)